# Why is the widget not getting resizeEvent?

Tags: qt, events, layout

I am trying to implement a new custom scrollbar. In order to do so, I have placed it onto the parent manually with `this->setParent(area);`

```
class QMacScrollBar : public QScrollBar
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QMacScrollBar(QAbstractScrollArea *area, Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget *parent = 0);

    virtual void paintEvent ( QPaintEvent * );
    QAbstractScrollArea *area;

signals:

public slots:
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
};

QMacScrollBar::QMacScrollBar(QAbstractScrollArea *area, Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget *parent) :
    QScrollBar(area)
{
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
    this->setOrientation(orientation);
    this->setParent(area);
    this->area = area;
}

void QMacScrollBar::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event){
    QRect geometry = QRect(QPoint(0, 0), event->size());
    if (area != NULL){
        geometry.setHeight(area->height());
        geometry.moveRight(area->width());
        geometry.adjust(-5, 0, -5, 0);
        this->setGeometry(geometry);
    }
    QScrollBar::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

I do get the first few resizes, but none after that. So far my guess is that when I resize the window, the QScrollArea doesnt actually resize, it just hides more of the viewport. I need the resize event because I need to move the place that I display the bar. How do I fix this?

EDIT: The only resizes I am getting are the ones that I spawn via connecting to the underlying scrollbar's `setRange` signal.

Comment: Do you have it in a layout on the parent or do you just add it to the parent?

Comment: I just added it to the parent, no layout.

Comment: Random guess - it does not resize because to receive rezise events from a parent widget it needs to be in a layout :)

Comment: Don't declare resizeEvent as a slot. I do not think it can cause something wrong, but that's clearly not standard. Events and slots are two different mechanisms.